# Control Read A String So Long windows phone app 8.1

Tags: string, pivot

I have a string so long (Actually, i write app read story), but i stuck when show Content of story in screen, i want design like pivot.
Every pivot item is a page. but i dont know, help me or show me link to get it

Comment: Try to rephrase your question. Focus on what you are trying to achieve, what programming language/GUI you are using and what problems your achivement would solve (not to have an X/Y problem).

Comment: Windows phone app 8.1. i am writing app reading book, so i have content of book very long, and i want divide content in many page, do you know i say ?